# change groupbox header text via code wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, groupbox

I would like to change the label text of a group box outside the designer. I tried the `content` property but it it does not works. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a label inside the design like this :

```
<GroupBox Height="608" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Width="375" x:Name="grp1">
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <Label Foreground="Blue" x:Name="lblGroupHeader"></Label>
            </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

then In code :

```
lblGroupHeader.Content = "The Name"
```

Comment: what is this an edit to your question ? the content Property of the GroupBox is the Content(everything in the GroupBox, if you want to change the Header then change the Property from Content to Header maybe ? which you are setting

Comment: I think this is the answer.